# What is the effect of the Dragon Ball?

Tags: nitrome-must-die

One of the weapons in [Nitrome Must Die](http://www.nitrome.com/games/nitromemustdie/index.html) is the Dragon Ball.

[image: Weapon icon image and a demonstration of a shot]

Through name and appearance, it appears to be based off of the Dragon Breath weapon from [Castle Corp](http://www.nitrome.com/games/castlecorp/index.html), where it is the most expensive item and fires an immensely powerful ball of purple energy that passes through walls and deals tons of damage.

The Dragon Ball doesn't quite seem to have that same flair in Nitrome Must Die. Is it truly a weak weapon that does pitiful damage and can't even punch through walls anymore, or does it have a special utility (kinda like the Peashooter and Toast) that produces its full power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Challenge Level on Level 73 uses the Dragon Ball as its weapon. I used this floor as an ample way to test the weapon in every conceivable way possible.

This led to the conclusion that **it's just a slow moving ball of purple energy**. It can neither pass through walls or enemies, it has a very slow rate of fire, and it only has 15 ammo. There are a plethora of better long range weapons available, and while its damage is decent (able to destroy Mini Octobosses in one hit), its downsides are just too hindering to make it that much of a viable weapon. The slow rate of fire makes it unsuitable for tough enemies, while the very poor ammo count makes it unsuitable for weak enemies.